# How can I find a list of active plugins on a web page in a browser window

Tags: firefox, youtube, flash

Say I open Youtube,and the video starts playing. How do I find out what in-browser and system plugins / resources are being used to play the music / video?

Asking because on my Firefox, about 50% of the time, when I open youtube, it starts playing the audio of the page in the background, even as the video loads. So when the video is playing, there's audio with it, but there's the same audio, with a small delay playing in the background.

I've tried disabling the extra flash plugin that most other guides about this recommend, and it hasn't helped. Now I want to find out what my browser is using to play the background music.

Comment: Is this a question about programming?

Comment: Isn't it? I'm sorry if I'm in the wrong place. I assumed developer tools /bug testing  would be something that programming covers.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest thing is probably to right-click on the video and check if the menu that appears is the typical Flash rc-menu or the browser native video right-click menu.